# Using Session variables in InsertCommand attribute of asp:LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access

I would like to use a Session variable created in the code-behind, in an actual  tag, primarily within the InsertCommand="" attribute:

Here is my code-behind (VB):

```
   Protected Sub RegSubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RegSubmitButton.Click
    For Me.i = 0 To UNPWListBox.Items.Count
        If (RegUNTextBox.Text = UNPWListBox.SelectedItem.Text) Then
            MsgBox("Username is unavailable. Please choose another username.")
            With RegUNTextBox
                .Text = ""
                .Focus()
            End With
        Else
            username = RegUNTextBox.Text
            password = RegPWTextBox.Text
            UNPWListBox.Items.Insert(UNPWListBox.SelectedIndex + 1, RegUNTextBox.Text)
            'UNPWListBox.Items.Add(username)
            UNPWListBox.SelectedItem.Text.Equals(username)
            UNPWListBox.SelectedItem.Value.Equals(password)
            Session(username) = username
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Dim newConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    Dim createTable = "CREATE TABLE [" + Session(username) + "] (ID int, Artist varchar(50), Title varchar(50), Label varchar(25), PressNumber varchar(15), YearReleased varchar(15), NMValue double, Notes string);"
    newConnection.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\allengatorpie\Documents\VBIIT1_DB.accdb")
    newConnection.Execute(createTable)
    Response.Redirect("AddVinyl.aspx")
```

Below is the ASP.NET source:

```
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
 Source=C:\Users\allengatorpie\Documents\VBIIT1_DB.accdb"
 ProviderName="System.Data.OleDb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM
 [allengatorpie]" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Session(username)] ([Artist], [Title], [Label],         [PressNumber], [YearReleased],
 [NMValue], [Notes]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)">
```

The Session(username) variable work perfectly in the code behind, but I need to use it in the ASP control so that SQL knows which table to insert the data into.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code below worked for me. I just decided to put it all in the back end, using an Application level variable. I am going to change this to Session, so that when the user logs out, it will clean the variable. Thanks for any and all input. 

        Protected Sub InsertButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [" + Application.Item("username") + "] ([Artist], [Title], [Label], [PressNumber], [YearReleased], [NMValue], [Notes]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    End Sub

Answer (score 1):

You can use inset parameters [More details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.insertparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example

```
<asp:sqldatasource
    id="SqlDataSource1"
    runat="server"
    connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind %>"
    ......>
      <insertparameters>
        <asp:formparameter name="CoName" formfield="CompanyNameBox" />
        <asp:formparameter name="Phone"  formfield="PhoneBox" />
      </insertparameters>
  </asp:sqldatasource>
```

Comment: What I am looking for (to put it bluntly) is to replace the table name in the SQL InsertCommand with the Session(username) variable I create at registration or login.